# Counting Distinct ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to count the ID of the table where it's last status is not equal 'Called'

`Table1
╔═════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ q_log_id║ q_id   ║ q_status ║
╠═════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║      1  ║ 1      ║ Waiting  ║
║      2  ║ 1      ║ Waiting  ║
║      3  ║ 1      ║ Called   ║
║      4  ║ 2      ║ Waiting  ║
║      4  ║ 2      ║ Waiting  ║
║      5  ║ 3      ║ Waiting  ║
║      5  ║ 3      ║ Waiting  ║
╚═════════╩════════╩══════════╝`

So, the count should return 2. I'm not good with queries so I need some help. I tried count with distinct but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: What do you mean by last status? please explain why the count should return 2. I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: Neither `2` nor `3` seem to hav a last status of `called`, assuming you mean to report the `q_id`, sorted by `q_log_id`. You need to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT q_id) AS Count
FROM table1
WHERE q_id IN (
    SELECT q_id
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY q_id
    HAVING MIN(q_status)<> 'Called'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with window analytic function `row_number`, you can do the order by on `q_log_id` and partition the rows on q_id column 
and get the last row and check if status is Called

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47f22/6)**

```
with cte
as
(
select * , row_number() over ( partition by q_id order by q_log_id desc) as rn
from table1
)
select count(q_id)
from cte
where rn =1
and q_status !='Called'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about 'Called' being the final entry you can count the q_id values where 'Called' never showed up.

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM
(SELECT q_id
   FROM table1
  GROUP BY q_id
  HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN q_status ='Called' THEN 1 END) IS NULL
) AS v
```

This works because the query

```
SELECT q_id,MAX(CASE WHEN q_status='Called' THEN 1 END)
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY q_id
```

gives a NULL if 'Called' is never associated with a q_id

```
Q_ID    MAX(CASE WHEN Q_STATUS='CALLED' THEN 1 END)
1       1
2       (null)
3       (null)
```